# SQL - COUNT() rows for two tables that are GROUP BY one column in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One table is the main table that holds most of the information. it has basically two important columns:

```
table2_id
type
```

The second table has only one of those columns and that's id. However, I have to GROUP BY type since that's what I am needing. But problem occurs because if I GROUP BY id on a joined statement it doesn't give me correct information. I am needing the other table to get matches AND mismatches from the first table.

EXAMPLE table 1:

```
id        type
100       admin
101       user
102       author
103       editor
104       customer
```

EXAMPLE table 2:

```
id
100
100
101
101
110
120
100
100
```

My Results need to look like:

```
type     total(COUNT()IN TABLE1)  intable2andtable1    difference
admin       200                         100                100
user        120                         100                 20
author      205                         200                  5
editor      80                           70                 10
customer    300                         100                200
```

So, some how I need to JOIN and COUNT() the tables. I was able to get the actual total from the first table. However, if I try to do anything with the ID it makes me add it to the GROUP BY clause and that's messing up my results.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT type , count(*) as total
FROM table1
GROUP BY type
```

and that will return:

```
type     total(COUNT()IN TABLE1)
admin       200 
user        120
author      205
editor      80
customer    300
```

However, I cannot get the second table involved and showing me the differences between the two.

EDIT: Here is a sqlfiddle to make it clearer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08951/2/0

Comment: Your desire result should be `SUM` instead of `COUNT` ? because  count is 2, and sum is 200 for admin. Or we need more data, because how `user` count is 120 ?

Comment: I guess your table1 and table2 are incomplete, there is no logic between your sample data and your desire result. Try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster and please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry. I thought I was clear. Here is a fiddle. Hopefully that will make more sense: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08951/2/0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the common field between your tables 1 and 2 is, however, assuming it's `id`, this query should be what you're after:

```
SELECT type,
  COUNT(t1.version_id) as t1_total,
  COUNT(t2.version_id) as t2_total,
  COUNT(t1.version_id) - COUNT(t2.version_id) as difference
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type ASC
```

Updated SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08951/20

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to count how many times each type is represented in table2, correct? How about this:

```
SELECT table1.type, COUNT(table2.id) 
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table2.id`
```

It should display something like this:

```
admin  4
user   2
```

Comment: I also need to count how many times type shows up in table1 as well.